# Getting the number of the order of the function in a recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

What is the easiest way to retrieve the order of the function in a recursive call. For instance, if we have a recursive function, it keeps calling itself until it finds the base case, and then it returns one function at a time. The first function returning is of order 0, the second is of order 1, and so on...What is an easy way to retrieve the order information? Say for instance, when it is the function of order three, I would like to do something special.

Edit: I want the function at the top of the stack to be zero.

Edit2: The problem I am trying to solve is to return the nth element of the in order traversal of a binary tree.

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you provide more detail and/or code?

Comment: You use a parameter to pass an argument that you increment for each call, or just do the entire thing iteratively. It sounds like you want the depth at each node in the recursion tree.

Comment: To find the `nth` element in a traversed tree, pass the a counter *into* and *out of* each recursive call. Siblings are fed the counter resulting from the traversal of previous siblings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting with a recursive function that looks like this

```
void recursive(int p1, String p2, long p3) {
    ...
    if (someCondition) {
        recursive(nextP1, nextP2, nextP3);
    }
}
```

change it to this:

```
void recursive(int p1, String p2, long p3, int level) {
    ...
    if (someCondition) {
        recursive(nextP1, nextP2, nextP3, level+1);
    }
}
```

Now Start off the level at zero by calling

```
recursive(initialP1, initialP2, initialP3, 0);
```

`level` will indicate the number of invocation of `recursive` above you.

**EDIT :** (zero-at-the-top)

You can also transform the function to return its level to implement the "zero at the top" strategy:

```
int recursive(int p1, String p2, long p3) {
    if (baseCase) {
        return 0;
    }
    ...
    int level = 0;
    if (someCondition) {
        level = 1+recursive(nextP1, nextP2, nextP3);
    }
    return level;
}
```

Note that in this case you cannot find your `level` until after the last recursive invocation has returned.

Comment: To add to this, you might want to keep your original recursive function which then calls the new one with the extra parameter. This way the caller (e.g. `main()`) doesn't know the difference.

Comment: Interesting, so what if I want the deepest function (the one at the top of the stack) to be zero?

Comment: @Keeto You cannot know what's your level with "zero on the top" until after the next invocation has returned (because you do not know how many of them there are going to be). You can return the level from the prior invocation, and add one to that to learn your level, but you can do it only "after the fact".

Comment: @Keeto Then they're all 0, since only the one currently executing (i.e. the deepest function) can do anything with that value. Or you want to know how deep the recursion ran beneath the current invocation, in which case you need a mutable object holding the maximum depth, which can be an AtomicInteger for example.

Answer (score 3):

The case dasblink has offered you covers the opposite of what you suggested implementation-wise because the level counter rises (increments) as you go deeper in the recursion.

If you want it to decrease as you go deeper in the recursion that would imply that you know the exact recursion depth beforehand.

In most cases if you know the exact recursion depth you won't be using recursion, you'll be using a loop (for, while, repeat/until etc.). In fact using recursion in such a case is less optimal because of the recursion stack that gets allocated (higher memory consumption) and loops are much more efficient.

Comment: +1 "In most cases if you know the exact recursion depth you won't be using recursion" This is a perfect observation!

Comment: Most of the time it's syntactically cleaner to use a recursive function. And if that bit of code needs to be reusable you'll be writing a function anyway so most people (including myself sometimes) zig when they should've zagged.

Comment: With using a recursive function you can easily end up with stack overflow. You can increase the stack by -ss Stacksize or -oss Stacksize. But still, each method call means overhead and if there the recursion is expected to be deep, it is something we should definitely avoid.

Answer (score 0):

- If the level 0 should be the last "nested call", then it is in general
  undecidable problem similar to the halting problem, because you can't
  just say "after 3 more nested calls, the function will return a
  value". It is possible to look ahead only by simulating the
  computation of the particular function.
- If the level 0 should be the first call, then it is quite simple and you     can use the level as a param of the method and increment it.

btw, interesting problem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem